# Custom title for facet display block

Tags: search

I am new to [Search API](https://drupal.org/project/search_api) and [Facet API](https://drupal.org/project/facetapi), any clue how to change the default Facet filter block title?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am sorry for such a silly question. You can change it from block title itself ..

Comment: I used patch from this issue https://drupal.org/node/1665164 for this problem.

Comment: Thank you @Eugene, actually just changing the block title solves it.

Comment: simple provide the block tilte at the the of block configuration ...........
that will override this title..

Answer (score 1):

To change the title of the block provided by the Facet API, go to admin/structure/block and choose the block of which you want to chage the title. Click on the `Configure` link and then change the title of block from Block Title textfield.